# Merge point shapefiles from different sub-folder using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, merge

I have different month (JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH.....DECEMBER) folder, each folder hold point shapefile for different month. I want to consider all month folder in a single program and output pass into as on different month folder.

I have written a code but its taking only single month at a time. How to put in my code different month workspace and output save into as same month folder?

I have shown below my code. This code taking too long time for merging the monthly point shapefile. Is there any function available for process the program?

```
import arcpy, os


out = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\MARCH' 
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\MARCH'  
shplist =  arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')
arcpy.Merge_management(shplist, os.path.join(out, 'Merged_003.shp'))
print 'done'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can step through all your folders and files using `arcpy.da.walk()` and merge the listed files for each of the folders.

This will get all shapefiles in each folder (if that folder is the name of a month) and merge them together into a new file stored in the same folder.  It will get the number of the month (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.) and the output file will be based on this number e.g. all shapefiles in the folder `OCTOBER` will be merged into a new shapefile called `Merged_010.shp`

```
import arcpy, os, calendar
topWorkspace = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2' 

# Get dict of months and month-number (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.)
months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)} 

# Get list of all folders that contain feature classes (shapefiles)
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(topWorkspace, topdown=True, datatype="FeatureClass") 

for folderPath, folderNames, fileNames in walk: 
    baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper() 
    if baseName.upper() in months: # Test that subfolder is a month name
        monthNumber = months[baseName] # Get month-number for use in output filename
        arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath 
        shapeFiles = [x for x in fileNames if os.path.splitext(x)[1].lower() == '.shp'] 
        # Merge all shapefiles in folder into new shapefile with name like Merged_001.shp (for January)
        arcpy.Merge_management(shapeFiles, "Merged_{}.shp".format(monthNumber))
```

---

I have modified the script a little to get around the `arcpy.da.Walk()` not working.  This instead uses `arcpy.ListWorkspaces()` to find all the folders, and then `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` to find all the shapefiles in each folder.

```
import arcpy, os, calendar
topWorkspace = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2' 
arcpy.env.workspace = topWorkspace

# Get dict of months and month-number (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.)
months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)} # Get dict of months and month number (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.)

# Step through list of all folders
for folderPath in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
    baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
    if baseName in months: # Test that subfolder is a month name
        monthNumber = months[baseName] # Get month-number for use in output filename
        arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath
        shapeFiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')
        # Merge all shapefiles in folder into new shapefile with name like Merged_001.shp (for January)
        arcpy.Merge_management(shapeFiles, "Merged_{}.shp".format(monthNumber)) # Merge shapefiles in folder into new shapefile with name Merged_001.shp (for January)
```